# How do use dictionary variables from two sources in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

We have an Ansible script that sends an email when a server has been updated. In the script I want to to use variables from two different locations for the send to addresses. The first location is from the inventory itself and is called owner_email the second is from the vars section of the roles called mb_addresses. In the script I am trying to figure out how to set it up. The relevant section is this:

```
- name: Send the report
  mail:
    host: our.mailserver.com
    port: 25
    to: 
      - "{{ owner_email }}"
      - "{{ mb_addresses }}"
    from: Tower@thiscompany.com
    subject: Linux monthly patch results
    body: "{{ lookup('file', '/depot/reports/patch/{{inventory_hostname}}_patch_report.txt') }}"
  delegate_to: localhost
  become: no
```

In the main.yml of the vars section mb_address is set up this way:

`mb_addresses: "first.email@thiscompany.com,second.email@thiscompany.com"`

The problem with that is I get the first email but the second is ignored.

The same happens if I set it up like this:

```
mb_addresses: '"first.email@thiscompany.com" "second.email@thiscompany.com"'
```

I have tried it like this:

```
mb_addresses:
- "first.email@thiscompany.com"
- "second.email@thiscompany.com"
```

When it is done this way neither email is picked up.

What I am trying to avoid is to go into each inventory item and add in a stock group to receive the completion emails.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the variables (wherever they might come from)

```yaml
owner_email: '"owner@thiscompany.com"'
mb_addresses: '"first.email@thiscompany.com" "second.email@thiscompany.com"'
```

Create the [list of addresses](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/mail_module.html#parameter-to) on your own. For example, test it first

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: to
      vars:
        to: "{{ [owner_email] + mb_addresses.split(' ') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
to:
  - '"owner@thiscompany.com"'
  - '"first.email@thiscompany.com"'
  - '"second.email@thiscompany.com"'
```

Test it at localhost, for example

```yaml
    - mail:
        host: localhost
        port: 25
        to: "{{ to }}"
        from: Tower@localhost
        subject: Linux monthly patch results
        body: Some of the 160 vulnerabilities might have been patched.
      vars:
        owner_email: '"admin@localhost"'
        mb_addresses: '"first.email@localhost" "second.email@localhost"'
        to: "{{ [owner_email] + mb_addresses.split(' ') }}"
```

sends the email

```
From: Tower@localhost
To: admin@localhost, first.email@localhost, second.email@localhost
Cc: 
Subject: Linux monthly patch results
Date: Tue, 06 Sep 2022 03:05:52 +0200
X-Mailer: Ansible mail module

Some of the 160 vulnerabilities might have been patched.
```

Comment: That worked just great thank you.